# Meta Stack Overflow's description in the Data Explorer hasn't been updated since it was the only meta

Tags: bug, status-completed, data-explorer

From the site list at https://data.stackexchange.com/:

> [image]
> Q&A about Stack Overflow, Server Fault and Super User

A tad dated. Consider building from real descriptions (the `audience` property of [`/sites` in the API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/sites#filter=default&run=true)).

Comment: Probably easier for the moment to just ask waffles to update the text; looking at various API integration is on my to-do list though, so I'll see if there's a more future-proof solution then.

Comment: I imagine this will probably be automatically fixed by the split.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was fixed by the MSO/MSE split.